# What is the API for the program-specific menu in Gnome?

Tags: menu, gtk, gnome

(This is *not* a question about the Applications menu in Gnome.)

I am using Gnome Classic 3.30.2, on Debian buster.  The top Gnome panel has a menu bar at the top left, which consists of three pull-down menus:  Applications, Places, and a third menu whose title is the name of the program whose window currently has keyboard focus.

By default, the program-specific menu only has one menu item:  Quit.  However, this menu can have custom items added to it by the program.  gnome-terminal is an example of an application which does this:

[image]

What is the name of this program-specific menu?  What is the API for adding these menu items?

All of my searches end up running into information about modifying the Applications menu, which has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 1):

After much searching, I found out that it’s called an [application menu](https://wiki.gnome.org/HowDoI/ApplicationMenu).  The API for it is `gtk_application_set_app_menu()`.

The application menu is being deprecated in favor of regular menu bars and header menus, so I suppose I shouldn’t put too much effort into supporting it.

(It’s not easy to find search results for “application menu” in Gnome, when I have to wade through false positives that talk about customizing the Applications menu.)